# Generic View Binding in Android Studio

Tags: xml, android-layout, kotlin, android-databinding

I'm in the process of writing abstract classes for a `ListAdapter` with a `SelectionTracker<Long>`. In my case, the `SelectionTracker` organizes items by `selectionKey`s via

```
interface TrackedListItem {

    var selectionKey : Long? 

}
```

Now, the items in the `RecyclerView` (and hence, the items stored in the `ListAdapter`) need to bind a "viewModel" (note this doesn't extend `ViewModel`, I'm just following the conventions outlined in [Android Sunflower](https://github.com/android/sunflower)). Sticking with those same conventions, my `ViewHolder` should take a `ViewBinding` as its argument:

```
abstract class TrackedItemViewHolder(val binding: ViewBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
```

I know ahead of time that the binding passed to the `ViewHolder` has a data variable `viewModel` that I can bind to, and I will know that this `viewModel` implements `TrackedListItem`. How can I create a generic layout (and thus binding) that effectively just passes:

```
<data><variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="...TrackedListItem" /></data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reasonable workaround for anyone interested is to declare:

```
abstract class TrackedItemViewHolder(val binding: ViewBinding) : 
                                    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){

    abstract val viewModel : TrackedListItem 
    ...
```

and then in implementations:

```
override val viewModel : TrackedListItem
    get() = (binding as bindingWithViewModel).viewModel!!
```